# How do you make 2D shadows in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, lighting

I tried to make 2D shadows by adding a spotlight like in this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvbQ9_bzx1k
I put a spotlight and tried using a different render pipeline but nothing works. Can someone help with a simple technique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Unity's experimental 2D Renderer with 2D lights  and the Shadow Caster 2D Component

Here is a Brackeys video about 2D Renderer and 2D lights:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nkgGyO9VG54&t=557s&ab_channel=Brackeys

The Documentation to the Shader Caster 2D Component:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.1/manual/2DShadows.html

You could also use this Asset without getting deep into the 2D Rendering.

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/hard-light-2d-152208

Comment: A more accurate and recent video is the one from Unity, which uses URP: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5l8vP90EvU

Comment: Thank you so much, the hard light 2d worked perfectly.

Comment: Awesome! I'd appreciate it if you'd mark this as an answer.